# Python : Show only necessary decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

I want python to show only decimal places that are actually necessary. For example :

```
x = 10
print("The value of 'x' is - " + float(x))
```

will print only :

```
The value of 'x' is - 10.0
```

This is really irritating as I am trying to make a calculator that uses `float()` in many places and I just can't seem to get rid of the `.0`.

I am looking for a really simplistic code. And, I don't want the number to be rounded in any way such that the original, accurate value is changed.

I am using Anaconda Spyder (Python 3.8) and I will be running the code on Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: Define "necessary". You only "know" that `x` is an integer because you hard-coded it to be one. But what if `x` were the result of some operation between two other values. How will you distinguish an integer result from a very-nearly-integer floating-point value?

Comment: @chepner, please understand that while making a calculator, I am not knowing the result. After the calculation, I want only the needed decimals. The below answers have good ways to distinguish between the same.

Comment: Consider how many decimal places are necessary for `x - 1` for `x = 1.1` and `x = 1.0`, based solely on the *result* of `x - 1`, not on knowing what was assigned to `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about checking if it's a float before printing?

```
x = 10
y= int(x) if int(x)==x else float(x)
print("The value of 'x' is - " + str(y))
```

Examples:

```
x = 10
y= int(x) if int(x)==x else float(x)

>>> print("The value of 'x' is - " + str(y))
The value of 'x' is - 10

x = 10.32
y= int(x) if int(x)==x else float(x)

>>> print("The value of 'x' is - " + str(y))
The value of 'x' is - 10.32

x = 10.0
y= int(x) if int(x)==x else float(x)

>>> print("The value of 'x' is - " + str(y))
The value of 'x' is - 10
```

Comment: What if `x = 10.0`?

Comment: Yes you are right, i updated the code and added it in the examples, thanks

Comment: This is the simplest answer of all!

Answer (score 0):

Checking whether the number is int or float

This is my first approach

1. Using isinstance (built in function)

```
number = input("Input number: ")


if  isinstance(number, int) == True:
    print(int(number))
else:
    print(number)
```

2. if value exists after decimal

```
number = float(input("Input number: "))

number_dec = str(number-int(number))[1:]


if  number_dec == '.0':
    print(int(number))
else:
    print(number)
```